# How to do in-query in jDBI?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

How can I execute somethings like this in jDBI ?

```
@SqlQuery("select id from foo where name in <list of names here>")
List<Integer> getIds(@Bind("nameList") List<String> nameList);
```

Table: `foo(id int,name varchar)`

Similar to @SelectProvider from myBatis.

Similar questions has been asked [How do I create a Dynamic Sql Query at runtime using JDBI's Sql Object API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642862/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-sql-query-at-runtime-using-jdbis-sql-object-api), but somehow answer is not clear to me.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve this issue? im trying the @BindIn but no luck :(

Answer (score 41):

This should work:

```
@SqlQuery("select id from foo where name in (<nameList>)")
List<Integer> getIds(@BindIn("nameList") List<String> nameList);
```

Don't forget to annotate class containing this method with:

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
```

annotation (beacuse under the hood JDBI uses Apache StringTemplate to do such substitutions). Also note that with this annotation, you cannot use '<' character in your SQL queries without escaping (beacause it is a special symbol used by StringTemplate).

Comment: How do I escape `<` inside the query?

Comment: Figured it out. You should do `\\<`

Comment: Need to add dependency as mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33249078/2987755

Comment: This works cool. But what if I want to apply `lower` function to each item in the list before doing the comparison. I tried `lower(name) in (lower(<nameList>))`. This of course doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @VikasPrasad Why not pre-process arguments in the code before executing the query?

Answer (score 9):

With PostgreSQL, I was able to use the ANY comparison and bind the collection to an array to achieve this.

```
public interface Foo {
    @SqlQuery("SELECT id FROM foo WHERE name = ANY (:nameList)")
    List<Integer> getIds(@BindStringList("nameList") List<String> nameList);
}

@BindingAnnotation(BindStringList.BindFactory.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface BindStringList {
    String value() default "it";

    class BindFactory implements BinderFactory {
        @Override
        public Binder build(Annotation annotation) {
            return new Binder<BindStringList, Collection<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void bind(SQLStatement<?> q, BindStringList bind, Collection<String> arg) {
                    try {
                        Array array = q.getContext().getConnection().createArrayOf("varchar", arg.toArray());
                        q.bindBySqlType(bind.value(), array, Types.ARRAY);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

NB: ANY is not part of the ANSI SQL standard, so this creates a hard dependency on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 8):

Use @Define annotation to build dynamic queries in jDBI.
Example:

```
@SqlUpdate("insert into <table> (id, name) values (:id, :name)")
public void insert(@Define("table") String table, @BindBean Something s);

@SqlQuery("select id, name from <table> where id = :id")
public Something findById(@Define("table") String table, @Bind("id") Long id);
```

Comment: I assume that you had to add `@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator` to the class to support `@Define`, but how did you get it to still do argument binding (`@Bind`) in addition to `@Define`?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the JDBI 3 Fluent API, you can use `bindList()` with an attribute:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>()
keys.add("user_name");
keys.add("street");

handle.createQuery("SELECT value FROM items WHERE kind in (<listOfKinds>)")
      .bindList("listOfKinds", keys)
      .mapTo(String.class)
      .list();

// Or, using the 'vararg' definition
handle.createQuery("SELECT value FROM items WHERE kind in (<varargListOfKinds>)")
      .bindList("varargListOfKinds", "user_name", "docs", "street", "library")
      .mapTo(String.class)
      .list();
```

Note how the query string uses `<listOfKinds>` instead of the usual `:listOfKinds`.

Documentation is here: http://jdbi.org/#_binding_arguments

Answer (score 0):

Use `@BindList` annotation.

Example:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id IN (<ids>)")
List<String> getNames(@BindList("ids") List<int> ids);
```