# Jdbi - how to bind a list parameter in Java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

We have an SQL statement which is executed by Jdbi (`org.skife.jdbi.v2`). For binding parameters we use Jdbi's `bind` method:

```
Handle handle = ...
Query<Map<String, Object>> sqlQuery = handle.createQuery(query);
sqlQuery.bind(...)
```

However we have a problem with in-lists and currently we are using `String.format` for this. So our query can look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tableOne.columnOne,
    tableTwo.columnTwo,
    tableTwo.columnThree
FROM tableOne
JOIN tableTwo
    ON tableOne.columnOne = tableTwo.columnOne
WHERE tableTwo.columnTwo = :parameterOne
    AND tableTwo.columnThree IN (%s)
```

`%s` is replaced by `String.format` so we have to generate a proper string in java code. Then after all `%s` are replaced we are using jdbi's `bind` method to replace all other parameters (`:parameterOne` or `?`).

Is there a way to replace `String.format` with jdbi? There is a method `bind(String, Object)` but it doesn't handle lists/arrays by default. I have found [this article](http://skife.org/jdbi/java/2011/12/21/jdbi_in_clauses.html) which explains how to write our own factory for binding custom objects but it looks like a lot of effort, especially for something that should be already supported.

Answer (score 17):

The [article you linked](http://skife.org/jdbi/java/2011/12/21/jdbi_in_clauses.html) also descibes the `@BindIn` annotation. This provides a general purpose implementiation for lists.

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public class MyQuery {
  @SqlQuery("select id from foo where name in (<nameList>)")
  List<Integer> getIds(@BindIn("nameList") List<String> nameList);
}
```

Please note that you'll have to escape all pointy brackets `<` like this `\\<`. There is a previous discusion on SO: [How to do in-query in jDBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424573/how-to-do-in-query-in-jdbi)

Comment: This works for me, but if I have both BindIn and Bind in the same query it doesn't seem to work. This happens to you too?

Comment: @Pablote please create a new StackOverflow question for this.

Comment: This works cool. But what if I want to apply `lower` function to each item in the list before doing the comparison. I tried `lower(name) in (lower(<nameList>))`. This of course doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to add an example since I recently spent considerable time getting a slightly more complex scenario to work :

**Query :**

```
select * from sometable where id <:id and keys in (<keys>)
```

**What worked for me :**

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public interface someDAO { 

    ....
    ....
    // This is the method that uses BindIn
    @Mapper(someClassMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("select something from sometable where age \\< :age and name in (<names>)")
    List<someclass> someMethod (@Bind("age") long age, @BindIn("names") List<string> names);

    @Mapper(someClassMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("select something from sometable where id = :id")
    List<someclass> someMethod1 (@Bind("id") long id);
    ...
    ...

}
```

Note: I **did have** to also add the below dependency since I am using

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The main thing to observe in the above example : You only need to escape the less than operator (i.e. < ) and not the <> that surround the collection variable (names).

As you can see I did not use a sql.stg file to write my queries in. Initially I incorrectly assumed that when using @UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator , we have to write the queries in the sql.stg file. However, somehow I never got my sql.stg file to work and I eventually reverted back to writing the query within the DAO class using @SqlQuery.

Answer (score 4):

For the most recent jdbi version things got easier:

```
public interface MyDao {
  @SqlQuery("select id from foo where name in (<nameList>)")
  List<Integer> getIds(@BindList("nameList") List<String> nameList);
}
```

- `@BindIn` → `@BindList`, and no longer requires StringTemplate

Reference: https://jdbi.org/