# Use a list of strings in IN clause with JDBI

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm using JDBI / Dropwizard for a project and would like to run some simple queries. I have a query like so:

`private static final String GET_STUFF = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE state IN (:desiredState)"`

I bind the variable in my method like so:

```
@Mapper(MyType.class)
@SqlQuery(GET_STUFF)
public MyType getStuff(@Bind(desiredState) List<String> states);
```

However, I get the following error when running:

```
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToCreateStatementException: 
Exception while binding 'desiredState'....
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

I'm passing in `states` as an `ArrayList` of type String, so I'm a bit confused what's going on here. Does anyone know the correct way to do `In` with JDBI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jdbi - how to bind a list parameter in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526233/jdbi-how-to-bind-a-list-parameter-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use annotation `@BindIn` instead of `@Bind`. 
Also, `:desiredState` should be written as `<desiredState>`

Comment: Looks like the required annotation was changed to `@BindList` in JDBI 3.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me (`JDBI 3.1.1`):

```
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.customizer.BindList;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.SqlUpdate;

public interface JdbiRoom {
    @SqlUpdate("update Room set available = 0 where id in (<roomIds>)")
    int markRoomsAsUnavailable(@BindList("roomIds") List<Long> roomIds);
}
```

Also, we discovered that `@BindIn` doesn't play well with `@UseStringTemplateSqlLocator`annotation, so `roomIds` must be passed as a query parameter when using named queries (see https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/1131) for details:

```
markRoomsAsUnavailable(roomIds) ::= <<
    update rooms set available = 0 where id in (<roomIds>)
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT ... WHERE xxx in (<uids>)")

@BindIn(value = "uids", onEmpty = BindIn.EmptyHandling.VOID) List<String> ids
```

don't forget to annotate your class

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
```