# How to use @SQLUpdate in JDBI to take a list of strings as a parameter?

Tags: java, jdbi

I have a SQL statement that needs to be executed multiple times with a list, and right now I'm using @SQLBATCH to do this.

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO table (name, id) values (:names, :id)")
public abstract void addName(
    @Bind("names") List<String> names,
    @Bind("id") long id);
```

I would like to return an int of the number of rows affected. So I looked into @SQLUpdate, but it seems like @SQLUpdate doesn't take a list as a parameter.

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO table (name, id) values (:names, :id)")
public abstract int addName(
    @Bind("names") List<String> names,
    @Bind("id") long id);
```

I'm getting this error: UnableToCreateStatementException: Exception while binding.

Is there any way I can return an int of the number of rows affected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526233/jdbi-how-to-bind-a-list-parameter-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use `@Update` this way.

Maybe you could employ `@BindIn` in some way I do not see but it is mainly to construct `in`-conditions like `id in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`.

Also I don't think that you need it because the number of elements in your names parameter already gives you the number of inserts that `@SqlBatch` executes.

So in the calling code you could just use `name.size()` to get the number of inserts that have been executed.