# How to use IN operator with JDBI?

Tags: java, mysql, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm trying to do a IN query using MYSQL JDBI on Dropwizard (not relevant, I assume).

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT id FROM table where field in (<list>)")
List<Integer> findSomething(@BindIn("list") List<String> someList);
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424573/how-to-do-in-query-in-jdbi), I've also annotated the class with

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
```

But when I'm starting the application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.stringtemplate.UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator.errorListener()
```

Does anyone have a good idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve it.

**1**. Using `UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator`

This annotation expects [Group Files](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST/Group+Files) with SQL statement in [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

Say I have this file PersonExternalizedSqlDAO

```
// PersonExternalizedSqlDAO.java

package com.daoexp.dao;

@@ExternalizedSqlViaStringTemplate3
@RegisterMapper(PersonMapper.class)
public interface PersonExternalizedSqlDAO {
    @SqlQuery
    List<Person> getPersonByNames(@BindIn("names") List<String> names);
}
```

Since we are using `UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator` we have to create `*.sql.stg` file in same class path. 
**For ex:** in `resources/com/daoexp/dao/PersonExternalizedSqlDAO.sql.stg`

```
group PersonExternalizedSqlDAO;

getPersonByNames(names) ::= <<
  select * from person where name in (<names>)
>>
```

Now you should be able to query without any issues.

---

**2**. Another approach is to use `ArgumentFactory` that handles your custom data type(in this case List) for JDBI with `@Bind`. This is most preferable approach.

So create this list argument factory

```
public class ListArgumentFactory implements ArgumentFactory<List> {
    @Override
    public boolean accepts(Class<?> expectedType, Object value, StatementContext ctx) {
        return value instanceof List;
    }

    @Override
    public Argument build(Class<?> expectedType, final List value, StatementContext ctx) {
        return new Argument() {
            @Override
            public void apply(int position, PreparedStatement statement, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
                String type = null;
                if(value.get(0).getClass() == String.class){
                    type = "varchar";
                } else if(value.get(0).getClass() == Integer.class){
                    // For integer and so on...
                } else {
                    // throw error.. type not handled
                }
                Array array = ctx.getConnection().createArrayOf(type, value.toArray());
                statement.setArray(position, array);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What this class does ?

- accepts instance of List
- convert the integer/string list to array and binds with prepared statement

Make sure you register this argument factory with your DBI instance.

```
final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "h2");
jdbi.registerArgumentFactory(new ListArgumentFactory());
```

Now you should be able to query using `List` in more simpler way(i.e) you have to use `@Bind`. Thats it.

```
@RegisterMapper(PersonMapper.class)
public interface PersonDAO {
    @SqlQuery("select * from person where name = any(:names)")
    List<Person> getPersonByNames(@Bind("names") List<String> names);
}
```

**Refer:**

- [jdbi doc](http://skife.org/jdbi/java/2011/12/21/jdbi_in_clauses.html)

**Additional Info:**

```
// PersonMapper.java
public class PersonMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Person> {

    public Person map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(r.getInt("id"));
        person.setName(r.getString("name"));

        return person;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems I can not use method two due to my SQL database being MySQL.  where array types are not supported (createArrayOf). I made it using your first method, with the sql.stg file. Thank you very much! And btw, ExternalizedSqlViaStringTemplate3  is deprecated, use UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator.

Comment: I am getting exception in solution 1 as, causing: org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getPersonByNames' at line 1, I think sql string are not getting replaced.

Comment: Seems like method two is also not supported in Oracle: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createArrayOf(PhysicalConnection.java:9283)`

Comment: @shiva, solution #1 works only for 3.2.1 version of org.antlr.stringtemplate. It is not working for the latest version.

Comment: I haven't used jdbi for quite a long time. Guess I can't help with that.

Answer (score 14):

I think, you use the `StringTemplate 4`.
You need to use `StringTemplate 3` instead of `StringTemplate 4`. Add this *dependency*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Will check later today, but in the code i pasted it does say version 3? "UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator"

Comment: Thanks, if I didn't add this dependency my Dropwizard app failed to start with an `AnnotationFormatError`: `Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.stringtemplate.UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator.errorListener()`.