# JDBI Select In using fluent interface (not object queries)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jdbi

Others have asked [how to do this with object queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424573/how-to-do-in-query-in-jdbi).

I want to map a list of strings to a IN clause in SQL (mysql) using JDBIs fluent interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible out of the box.
When I had to implement similar thing, I've used StringBuilder, StringUtils.repeat("?,") to build a prepared query, and then for-loop to bind values from collection as query arguments.