# Postgres query must be of type boolean

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

I am using skife to help with my database queries.  I have the query and method below.

```
@SqlQuery("select * from profile where profile_id >= :from and profile_id < :to")
List<Profile> findAllInRange(@Bind("from")int from, @Bind("to")int to);
```

I get the following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type bigint
```

But if I execute this query

```
select * from profile where profile_id >= 1 and profile_id < 50
```

my RDBMS returns the results successfully.

What am I missing?

Comment: parse it to a boolean

Comment: @ja08prat what does that mean?  I am sorry I don't follow.

Comment: try with put \\ before the '<' operator

Comment: @MinMiguelM that was exactly it!

Comment: @MinMiguelM why does that make it work?

Comment: found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19535301/5338668

Comment: @JamalH Because the < operator is used to bind a list of names, for example profile_id in (< list >), so is neccessary to ignore it when is not for that purpose

Comment: @MaxPower parse by type casting the operation to a boolean

Comment: Take a look at this sample - https://github.com/wololock/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/45287455 I've reflected DAO and Profile entity, SQL query without escaping works like a charm. There is a test with embedded PostgreSQL added to prove it works by default.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to MinMiguelM

I needed to place `\\` before the `<` operator

Comment: what is background?

Comment: Update to recent version of JDBI 2.x--this should fix the improper parsing of < and >.